# Show lim sup (an) = lim inf (an) for increasing for increasing sequence of subsets.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, limsup-and-liminf

Let $X$ be a set and let $(A_n)$ be a sequence of subsets of $X$.

Show that;

If $A_n$ is increasing then $\liminf (A_n) = \limsup (A_n) = \bigcup^{\infty}_{n=1} A_n$

So what I know from the question that I think I'll need for a solution is that
  $\limsup a_n := \bigcap^{\infty}_{n=1} \bigcup_{k{\geq}n} A_k$
  $\liminf a_n := \bigcup^{\infty}_{n=1} \bigcap_{k{\leq}n} A_k$
            and the sequence is increasing so $A_k \leq A_{k+1}$

I'm not to sure how to put this together into a solution, help please ?
I'm also required to show for a decreasing sequence $\liminf (A_n) = \limsup (A_n) = \bigcap^{\infty}_{n=1} A_n$ but I'm sure the solutions will be similar.

Comment: For any sequence $(A_n)_n$ of sets we have $x\in \lim \sup A_n$ iff  $x \in A_n$ for infinitely many $n$ and $x\in \lim \inf A_n$ iff $x\in A_n$ for all but finitely many $n.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $A_1\subset A_2\subset A_3\subset\cdots$, then, for each $n\in\mathbb N$,$$\bigcup_{k\geqslant n}A_k=\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k$$and therefore$$\limsup_nA_n=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k=\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k.$$On the other hand, for each $n\in\mathbb N$,$$\bigcap_{k\geqslant n}A_k=A_n$$and therefore$$\liminf_nA_n=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n.$$

Comment: Great thanks! Just to check, that last line should be $\liminf_nA_n=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ right ? Since $\liminf_nA_n=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \bigcap_{k\geq n}^\infty A_k$ and you pointed out $\bigcap_{k\geqslant n}A_k=A_n$

Comment: Sure! It was a typo.